# CSS layers - z-index

Tags: css, styles, css-position, z-index, layer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvQOo.png)
I have added this check button into the card, and added position into it so I can put it in the corner on the left, but when I get the button out of the card corner I got disappear , even when I use z-index!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have `overflow: hidden;` set for the `.note-card`. If you want to keep it, you will have to move your check outside that container or switch to `overflow: visible` and deal with the cut-off text differently, either by making the box taller, shortening text, or wrapping that text in another `div` that then would have the `overflow: hidden` to just cut off the text.

Answer (score 0):

The button disappears because you have the `overflow` property set to `hidden` on the `.note-card` element. Try setting this property to `visible`.

Also providing a code snippet can allow others to help you in a better manner as screenshots of code are not that helpful.